# How to delete or hide by "KML" code temporary place marks that I plotted by "KML" code in Google earth and Plot new place marks?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I Embed GE in my app and try to plot some driving route on it. I tried Place marks and "Line String"  coordinates to plot that. what I am looking for is a way that I update the plot and plot a new route by new coordinates, So I need a way to delete old place marks and plot new one by "KML" code or other programing techniques.

In other word I want to delete temporary places folder by programming instead of GUI "Delete Contents" in GE.

Any help is appreciated.
thanks ....

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you're trying to do.  How are you doing "Embed GE in my app", since there is not currently an embeddable version nor API for Google Earth. Per the stackoverflow question asking guidelines, please post more info on what you've tried.

Comment: thanks for your comment Christiaan, Active-x Classes is utilized to perform this... I initialize and open the GE and then load my KML file on it ... what I want for next step is a way to delete the plotted KML file which is now as a temporary place mark and then refresh the KML Loading for new plot...it is useful to mention that I am using library which is attached [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Code/Embed-Google-Earth-in-Your-Application-Using-LabVIEW/ta-p/3528533?profile.language=en)

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams thanks for your comment in advance and I appreciate your future helps ...

Comment: I don't think that loading earth via active-x is a supported api, so afraid I don't know how to help.  That said, if you can add a KML, you should be able to delete it.  Or, if you're wanting to update KMLs on the fly, you can either use a networklink that updates regularly and pulls in new KML from a server each time, or use a KML NetworkLink with an Update element, to change already loaded KML.